# Error refreshing libs with cn1 library

Tags: java, codenameone

I get the following error when trying to 'refresh cn1 libs' with a small library I wrote (the library is [here](https://github.com/jegesh/cn1-device-logs)):

`Cannot use a cn1lib with java version greater then the project java version`

Following that is a long stack trace, and the last line is green, reading

`BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`

Obviously, one of these is a lie.  It seems the build is not successful, since I have no access to the native methods.  I recall that once my cn1 project's jdk was set to 5, but I since changed it to 8, and I can't find anywhere in the project settings that it's still set to 5.  I tried, just for the sake of ruling it out, setting the cn1 library's jdk to 5, but the error didn't go away.

What am I doing wrong?

## Edit

I found a number of targets in the build.xml file where the java version was set to 1.5.  Even after changing all of them to 1.8, the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a cn1lib is written with Java 8 and you created a project targeting Java 5 language level they will not be compatible (the reverse should work through).

Make sure that you created a Java 8 project, if this is an existing project make sure to follow the [instructions for converting it](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/java-8-support.html) including the `java.version=8` build hint.

Comment: Yeah, it was the build hint that was missing.  Thanks as usual, Shai!

Comment: Now the errors went away, but I can't import the package or use the class.  I even added an `internal_tmp` folder as per Diamond's suggestion above.  Is there anything else I need to do differently?

Comment: I also can't send builds if the library .jar is included in my project, I get 'symbol not recognized' errors from some of the Android methods imported in the native util implementation class.

Comment: You can't just change the classpath or embed an arbitrary jar that isn't a cn1lib.

Comment: The problem in the end was that I didn't understand the instructions for writing the bridge class.  Now it all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your source and I found an issue when I tried to clean build.

Even though you didn't write any code for other native platforms, you should keep their folders intact in the **native** directory.

After creating the folders, namely: ios, j2me, javascript, javase, rim, win and internal_tmp, I clean build and cn1lib was generated in the **dist** folder. I copied this to one of my open projects, refresh libs and it works fine.

I tried the cn1lib with Java 5, 7 and 8 projects, it works fine in all without issues.

I believe the problem is from the folders mentioned above. Follow the steps above to get it to work. If you encounter an issue, please post the full stacktrace.